# php pdo sqlite shows wrong result in sqlfiddle it shows ok

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sqlite

good evening,

when i run simulation of my code using sqlite browser i get the right result even if sqlfiddle shows my code working fine. but when i try it in php pdo it show wrong result.

here is sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9644d/1  <~~ in this link it works fine but in php pdo it's not working...

here is the code i am using to call my data

```
SELECT id,name,type,MIN(price) as price,MAX(best_selling) as best_selling 
FROM Perf 
GROUP BY type,name 
ORDER BY best_selling DESC, id ASC
```

if there is an alternative to call my code that will work fine.

my plan is to get result of **best_selling** with **lowest price** available in database then group by **type and name** then sort by **best_selling** to show first

Comment: What is the PDO code, and what are the results there?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote :) Please accept the answer if you find it confirmed what you wanted. If you have minor changes to your question then I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is test data in an SQLFiddle :) That gets my attention - thanks - it really does help me :)

I loaded all the information into an SQLite Database here :) I use an SQLite IDE. It works fine and exports ok :)

### Valid SQL query?

I use the SQLlite IDE to check your query. Hmm, It isn't a valid query ;-/ Why?

You use a 'group by' clause. That is ok. However, **every other selected column must be in a group function** to be valid SQL in other SQL Engines.

With that in mind: I decided to make it easier to debug the queries by including 'min' and 'max' values in the queries.

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9644d/2 for a valid SQLite SQL query that I actually used. I used this query in PHP as well.

### Working SQL Query

So: Here is the query I used:

```
SELECT min(id) AS id_start, 
            max(id) AS id_end, 
            name,
            type,
            MIN(price)            as min_price,
            MAX(price)            as max_price,
            MAX(best_selling) as best_selling 
FROM Perf
GROUP BY type,
         name 
ORDER BY best_selling DESC, 
                 id_end ASC
```

*Results:*

```
id_start    id_end  name    type    min_price   max_price   best_selling
102 103 another_thing   plastic 10  30  2
101 105 something   glass   20  50  2
100 100 random322312    glass   20  20  1
104 104 something   stone   30  30  1
106 106 random_12321312 glass   111 111 1
107 107 random_12321512 glass   111 111 1
108 108 random_1232312  glass   111 111 1
109 109 random_1236312  glass   111 111 1
97  97  rand55312   glass   20  20  1
98  98  ran62312    glass   20  20  1
99  99  ran44232312 glass   20  20  1
```

### The above SQLite IDE code works...

Now we need to show that that the PDO version of this, using an SQLite database returns the same results...

### Convert Working SQL To PHP using PDO...

From here it is just a matter of converting working SQL code in the IDE
Into working code in PHP using PDO. It cannot be that difficult?

0) Create a valid PDO connection to valid SQLite Database. see the export below.

1) Copy the SQL:

```
    $sql = "SELECT min(id) AS id_start, 
                max(id) AS id_end, 
                name,
                type,
                MIN(price)            as min_price,
                MAX(price)            as max_price,
                MAX(best_selling) as best_selling 
            FROM Perf
            GROUP BY type,
                     name 
            ORDER BY best_selling DESC, 
                    id_end ASC";

    $stmt = $dbPdo->prepare($sql);  
    $stmt->execute();
```

----- the results ---

### See all the results:

```
// get them all
$stmt->fetchAll();
```

### The results:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                              $stmt->fetchAll()                               │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
array (11) [
    array (7) [
        'id_start' => string (3) "102"
        'id_end' => string (3) "103"
        'name' => string (13) "another_thing"
        'type' => string (7) "plastic"
        'min_price' => string (2) "10"
        'max_price' => string (2) "30"
        'best_selling' => string (1) "2"
    ]
    array (7) [
        'id_start' => string (3) "101"
        'id_end' => string (3) "105"
        'name' => string (9) "something"
        'type' => string (5) "glass"
        'min_price' => string (2) "20"
        'max_price' => string (2) "50"
        'best_selling' => string (1) "2"
    ]
    array (7) [
        'id_start' => string (3) "100"
        'id_end' => string (3) "100"
        'name' => string (12) "random322312"
        'type' => string (5) "glass"
        'min_price' => string (2) "20"
        'max_price' => string (2) "20"
        'best_selling' => string (1) "1"
    ]
    array (7) [
        'id_start' => string (3) "104"
        'id_end' => string (3) "104"
        'name' => string (9) "something"
        'type' => string (5) "stone"
        'min_price' => string (2) "30"
        'max_price' => string (2) "30"
        'best_selling' => string (1) "1"
    ]
    array (7) [
        'id_start' => string (3) "106"
        'id_end' => string (3) "106"
        'name' => string (15) "random_12321312"
        'type' => string (5) "glass"
        'min_price' => string (3) "111"
        'max_price' => string (3) "111"
        'best_selling' => string (1) "1"
    ]
    array (7) [
        'id_start' => string (3) "107"
        'id_end' => string (3) "107"
        'name' => string (15) "random_12321512"
        'type' => string (5) "glass"
        'min_price' => string (3) "111"
        'max_price' => string (3) "111"
        'best_selling' => string (1) "1"
    ]
    array (7) [
        'id_start' => string (3) "108"
        'id_end' => string (3) "108"
        'name' => string (14) "random_1232312"
        'type' => string (5) "glass"
        'min_price' => string (3) "111"
        'max_price' => string (3) "111"
        'best_selling' => string (1) "1"
    ]
    array (7) [
        'id_start' => string (3) "109"
        'id_end' => string (3) "109"
        'name' => string (14) "random_1236312"
        'type' => string (5) "glass"
        'min_price' => string (3) "111"
        'max_price' => string (3) "111"
        'best_selling' => string (1) "1"
    ]
    array (7) [
        'id_start' => string (2) "97"
        'id_end' => string (2) "97"
        'name' => string (9) "rand55312"
        'type' => string (5) "glass"
        'min_price' => string (2) "20"
        'max_price' => string (2) "20"
        'best_selling' => string (1) "1"
    ]
    array (7) [
        'id_start' => string (2) "98"
        'id_end' => string (2) "98"
        'name' => string (8) "ran62312"
        'type' => string (5) "glass"
        'min_price' => string (2) "20"
        'max_price' => string (2) "20"
        'best_selling' => string (1) "1"
    ]
    array (7) [
        'id_start' => string (2) "99"
        'id_end' => string (2) "99"
        'name' => string (11) "ran44232312"
        'type' => string (5) "glass"
        'min_price' => string (2) "20"
        'max_price' => string (2) "20"
        'best_selling' => string (1) "1"
    ]
]
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
Called from K:\developer\webapps\testitapp\tests\systest\phpunit\sogQ46632424_sqlite.ph
```

// ...............................
The exported SQLite database that will be used:

```
--
-- File generated with SQLiteStudio v3.1.1 on Mon Oct 9 00:24:55 2017
--
-- Text encoding used: System
--
PRAGMA foreign_keys = off;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Table: Perf
CREATE TABLE Perf
    ("id" TEXT, "name" TEXT, "type" TEXT, "price" INTEGER, "best_selling" INTEGER);
INSERT INTO Perf (id, name, type, price, best_selling) VALUES ('97', 'rand55312', 'glass', 20, 1);
INSERT INTO Perf (id, name, type, price, best_selling) VALUES ('98', 'ran62312', 'glass', 20, 1);
INSERT INTO Perf (id, name, type, price, best_selling) VALUES ('99', 'ran44232312', 'glass', 20, 1);
INSERT INTO Perf (id, name, type, price, best_selling) VALUES ('100', 'random322312', 'glass', 20, 1);
INSERT INTO Perf (id, name, type, price, best_selling) VALUES ('101', 'something', 'glass', 20, 1);
INSERT INTO Perf (id, name, type, price, best_selling) VALUES ('102', 'another_thing', 'plastic', 10, 1);
INSERT INTO Perf (id, name, type, price, best_selling) VALUES ('103', 'another_thing', 'plastic', 30, 2);
INSERT INTO Perf (id, name, type, price, best_selling) VALUES ('104', 'something', 'stone', 30, 1);
INSERT INTO Perf (id, name, type, price, best_selling) VALUES ('105', 'something', 'glass', 50, 2);
INSERT INTO Perf (id, name, type, price, best_selling) VALUES ('106', 'random_12321312', 'glass', 111, 1);
INSERT INTO Perf (id, name, type, price, best_selling) VALUES ('107', 'random_12321512', 'glass', 111, 1);
INSERT INTO Perf (id, name, type, price, best_selling) VALUES ('108', 'random_1232312', 'glass', 111, 1);
INSERT INTO Perf (id, name, type, price, best_selling) VALUES ('109', 'random_1236312', 'glass', 111, 1);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;
```

Comment: thanks mate your answer is what i was looking for. +1